# How to establish connectivity between nw.js app and unix socket domain

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, sockets, unix

I've created an simple app with nw.js i wanted it to communicate to UNIX socket domain client(written in c++) to send data to UNIX socket domain server(written in c++).

As both UNIX socket domain client and server are running forever listening for data.How can i pass data from nw.js app to forever running c++ code(client) and receive data back to nw.js app when there is any data available at c++ code forever running code(client).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20809607/2624876) mentioning [`net.createConnection(path[, connectListener])`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_net_createconnection_path_connectlistener)

Comment: Please use the close button to close as duplicate instead of answering with a link to another answer (or flag as duplicate if you don't have enough rep).

Comment: @DenysSéguret I'm not aware of a close button. Is this something moderators/people with 200000 rep have? Looks like I could flag the question "for serious problems or moderator attention", but there's no way I'm going to click a button like that on a completely well-intentioned question.